# phpMailer setting breaking HTML template in Outlook

Tags: phpmailer

We're purchase SimpleApp from the themeforest store. When sending a template via stampready, the template is delivered 100% and renders exactly as per the "design builder". Taking the exact same sourcecode from the mailer, and sending it through phpMailer, causes some strange template issues. Tables dont stack correctly leading to the template looking incorrect. When comparing the source code it is however identical (literally took it via "view source"). This leads me to believe there is some encoding or changes that I need to set:

- Currently we already set the mailer character set as UTF-8
- encoding is 8-bit
- Mail is sent via SMTP
- isHTML is set
- SimpleApp also provides "HTML" templates but these do the exact same
- I have also tried "wraptext" method as seen in other examples, but driving me insane as I've spent days trying to find out what exactly is causing this.

As the sourcecode works in 1 builder (and the HTML templates seems to do the same) I am leading to believe this to be a configuration setting that I need to change in phpMailer. I know phpMailer sends the mail "as is" but there has to be something causing this and unfortunately Outlook does not have a lot of debugging options :)

Here is an example as sent via stampready: [image]

Here is an example taking the exact same sourcecode but sending it through phpMailer: [image]

Comment: What's the smallest example you can come up with that shows this happening? Can you show the source of the original HTML and the encoded version in the message?

Comment: @Synchro I would share the source code but as we've purchased it I don't know if we can to be honest (making this extremely difficult). I have reached out to the simpleapp developer twice but no feedback from him.

Comment: meh not even worth the effort, I've put together a number of other templates via stampready and they work perfectly, a real pity as we liked the simpleapp platform, will try get a refund

Comment: Fair enough. Relying on unbounded table stacking for alignment is a pretty bad idea anyway if you ask me. If you're going to do that, make them rows of one table.

Comment: Try using mailsnag.com for both tests and compare raw data - mailsnag lets you see raw data and each part separately for debugging